# Can particular bit number be called flag?

Tags: c++, computer-science, naming

Enum of flags:

```
enum class AbilityFlag
{
  FLY = 1 << 0, // 0x01
  WALK = 1 << 1, // 0x02
  JUMP = 1 << 2, // 0x04
  SWIM = 1 << 3, // 0x08
};
```

But can it be called flag if it is particular bit?

```
enum class AbilityFlag
{
  FLY = 0, // bit no. 0
  WALK = 1, // bit no. 1
  JUMP = 2, // bit no. 2
  SWIM = 3, // bit no. 3
};
```

Or only value that represents bit combination(like in first example) is called "flag"?

Comment: Call it whatever you want...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I meant if definition of flag refers only to value that represents corresponding bit, or also to particular bit number. why should i name things with wrong names

Comment: Did you consider performing some research? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type in your first example is called *bit field* or *flag field*. Each constant is represented by a single bit. This means that you can combine different settings within one variable by using the bitwise *or* operator, for example `ability = WALK | JUMP`. Later you can extract the single property by using a bitwise *and*, like `canJump = ability & JUMP` This is not possible in your second enum, where `WALK | JUMP` has the same value as `SWIM`.

Variables with any of these types can be called flags. Generally the term *flag* is used for any discete valued variable that indicates some property. Often boolean variables are used as flags.